# Run FTP Voyager Transfer Command Line from SSIS Process task

Tags: ssis, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to send a file over SFTP (FTP Voyager) by using the command line through a SSIS Process Task. Here's the argument I enter:

```
/C "C:\Program Files (x86)\RhinoSoft.com\FTP Voyager\FTP Voyager.exe"  
profile="SVB TransACT Gateway" autoquit=1 
put="C:\Data Warehouse\SVB Data\CONS2015060507""
```

If I run the code (without the starting `/C`) directly in a command window, it executes fine. If I run it within the SSIS package, I get the following error.

```
Date,Source,Severity,Step ID,Server,Job Name,Step Name,Notifications,Message,Duration,Sql Severity,Sql Message ID,Operator Emailed,Operator Net sent,Operator Paged,Retries Attempted
06/10/2015 16:25:29,jbTestPackage,Error,0,CARLSBERG,jbTestPackage,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User HAHNFAMILY\hnadmin.  The last step to run was step 1 (Run Package).,00:00:06,0,0,,,,0
06/10/2015 16:25:29,jbTestPackage,Error,1,CARLSBERG,jbTestPackage,Run Package,,Executed as user: CARLSBERG\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.5500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:25:29 PM  Error: 2015-06-10 16:25:35.63     Code: 0xC0029151     Source: Execute Process Task Execute Process Task     Description: In Executing "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/c "c:\data warehouse\svb data\ftptransfer.bat"" at ""<c/> The process exit code was "255" while the expected was "0".  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  4:25:29 PM  Finished: 4:25:35 PM  Elapsed:  6.344 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:06,0,0,,,,0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to invoke a connection profile named "SVB TransACT Gateway".

If the profile is stored in Windows registry, the account that runs the SSIS may not have an access to that.

You should better try to specify the session on command-line using parameters like the `host=`, `user=`, etc.
See https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Command-line-options-for-FTP-Voyager

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Opens an FTP (not sFTP mind you) connection and stops there.

Comment: I didn't find a way to open SFTP with FTP Voyager. You should better use another command-line SFTP client with good documentation.